# Server App - Users

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-lion

I'm using mac OSX lion server, and I'm trying to setup a user account with access to different services.

I had to create the user in Prefs > users and groups, because it wouldn't work in the Server app. In the server app, it kept saying "This operation couldn't be completed". I managed to create the user in the system prefs, but now I'm back in the server app and cannot update the services the user has access to. The checkboxes are all there for e.g. Address book, file sharing etc, but I can't deselect any of them...

Any ideas on why I can't change a user's access to services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the services are greyed out, they are being set at a group level which propagates down to the user. Check their group membership and remove them from the relevant group.

You need to remember any users you create in System Prefs are in the local directory and won't be able to log on to some network services.